# How to refresh Internet Explorer using SendMessage?

Tags: internet-explorer, refresh, sendmessage

does anybody know how to refresh the Internet Explorer (like by pressingthe F5 key) but using some "backdoor" like PostMessage or SendMessage? The internet Explorer Window is not active so I can't use the keyboard.

Thanks

(Language doesnt matter)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your need a little better now.

Create a new webpage on your machine with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://google.com" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0">
            If you see this - Get a new browser.
    </iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

Then double click to open that in your browser window.

If you are the developer of the webpage, simply add the meta-tag you see in the HEAD section to auto refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

There are IE add-ons that auto refresh pages for you. Fist random freeware tool I found: [AutoRefresher for IE](http://www.download.com/AutoRefresher-for-IE/3000-12777_4-10062693.html). If you don't like this particular one, there are others to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard... to start a macro doing this!

With AutoHotkey:

```
#^x:: ControlSend Edit1, {Enter}, ahk_class IEFrame
```

Win+Ctrl+X to refresh the window.
Note I have the following settings in the script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
SendMode Input
```

It works, even if the window hasn't the focus.
You can also do a loop for periodic refresh.

Problem: the address bar must be present, and the URL to refresh must be there...
But it is the most reliable way I found, I tried:

```
 #^x:: ControlSend ahk_parent, {F5}, Microsoft Internet Explorer
```

but it wasn't working each time. Working better with a minimized window, curiously...

Answer (score 1):

Use this Vb script

`Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Iexplore"
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"`

save it to anything.vbs and run it